# Is it possible to get pydantic v2 to dump json with sorted keys?

Tags: python, json, pydantic

In the pydantic v1 there was an option to add kwargs which would get passed to `json.dumps` via [`**dumps_kwargs`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson). However, in pydantic v2 if you try to add extra kwargs to `BaseModel.json()` it fails with the error `` TypeError: `dumps_kwargs` keyword arguments are no longer supported. ``

Here is example code with a workaround using `dict()`/`model_dump()`. This is good enough as long as the types are simple, but it won't work for the more complex data types that pydantic knows how to serialize.

Is there a way to get `sort_keys` to work in pydantic v2 in general?

```py
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel


class JsonTest(BaseModel):
    b_field: int
    a_field: str

obj = JsonTest(b_field=1, a_field="one")

# this worked in pydantic v1 but raises a TypeError in v2
# print(obj.json(sort_keys=True)

print(obj.model_dump_json())
# {"b_field":1,"a_field":"one"}

# workaround for simple objects
print(json.dumps(obj.model_dump(), sort_keys=True))
# {"a_field": "one", "b_field": 1}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is an elegant solution but you could leverage the fact that dictionaries (since python 3.7) preserve an order of elements:

```
from typing import Any, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_serializer


class JsonTest(BaseModel):
    b_field: int
    c_field: int
    a_field: str

    @model_serializer(when_used='json')
    def sort_model(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return dict(sorted(self.model_dump().items()))


obj = JsonTest(b_field=1, a_field="one", c_field=0)
print(obj.model_dump_json())
# {"a_field":"one","b_field":1,"c_field":0}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi!**

Try using the `model_dump` method and the `sort_keys` parameter of `json.dumps` to achieve sorting of keys in the JSON output in `pydantic v2`.

```
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel

class JsonTest(BaseModel):
    b_field: int
    a_field: str

obj = JsonTest(b_field=1, a_field="one")

# Use the model_dump method to get a dictionary and then sort the keys
sorted_json = json.dumps(obj.model_dump(), sort_keys=True)

print(sorted_json)
# {"a_field": "one", "b_field": 1}
```

This will produce a `JSON` striing with `sorted keys`. The `model_dump` method returns a dictionary representation of the `Pydantic model`, and then `json.dumps` is used with the `sort_keys=True` parameter to sort the keys alphabeticaly in the resulting `JSON string`.

You can read more here: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/

Comment: yes, that's the workaround i posted i the original question. i was hoping there was a more robust solution that could handle the additional dtypes that pydantic can do https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump_json

Answer (score 0):

As I only wanted it sorted for a single dump I used the following:

```py
sorted_json = json.dumps(json.loads(obj.model_dump_json()), sort_keys=True)
```

not pretty or efficient, but it works.