# Is overriding `model_dump_json()` a viable way to handle `sort_keys` and `separators` in Pydantic V2 `model_dump_json()`?

Tags: json, python-3.x, serialization, model, pydantic

I have been migrating to Pydantic v2 and came across an issue where we had been specifying a few kwargs that are not available in v2 for JSON dumping. Namely, those kwargs are `sort_keys` and `separators`. The question of how to handle this properly has no answer yet ([Is it possible to get pydantic v2 to dump json with sorted keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77076597/is-it-possible-to-get-pydantic-v2-to-dump-json-with-sorted-keys)).

One hack that I did to accomplish this defeats some of the purpose of Pydantic. It was to override `model_dump_json()` in my BaseModel class, kind of like this:

```py
def model_dump_json(self, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
  separators = kwargs.pop("separators", (",", ":"))
  sort_keys = kwargs.pop("sort_keys", True)
  result_dict = self.model_dump(*args, **kwargs)
  return json.dumps(result_dict, sort_keys=sort_keys, separators=separators)
```

This seems pretty bad for a couple reasons, but **my question is** *why exactly is this bad?* I need to be able to explain to others why this is bad in great detail but I am struggling with the technical reasons. Also, how does this compare to Pydantic v1?

There is a standard in one of our models, defined by community specs, demanding the sorting of keys in the model for bytes-serialization reasons, so this is a required attribute of this base model.

My answer as to why this is bad: I think it has do with the fact that we are skipping the rust functions which defeats the purpose of pydantic. However, the performance loss is perhaps negligible as we don't often dump to JSON, except when writing to files.

Are there any additional reasons why this is bad?

In my mind, this has to be exactly what Pydantic v1 was doing anyway, so it is probably okay to go to production like this.

There are a couple of issues on Pydantic's GitHub that encompass this, such as https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6606, so perhaps we just need to wait until the feature is provided to properly handle this problem.

But I am struggling to feel confident in what to do until then.

Comment: The other question you linked does have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077890/9723036). Does that answer suit your need?